# ASP Textbox not visible

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I am trying to display a textbox with ASP (code taken from W3 Schools) but when I run the website using my local IIS server I only see the "Enter your name:" label.

```
<script runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   lbl1.Text="Your name is " & txt1.Text
End Sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
Enter your name:
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
<p><asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: This is a project for someone who insists to use ASP so I can't do PHP and I don't know ASP.

Thanks.

*EDIT* Here is the rendered HTML

```
<html><head><script runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   lbl1.Text="Your name is " & txt1.Text
End Sub
</script>



</head><body>

<form runat="server">
Enter your name:
<asp:textbox id="txt1" runat="server">
<asp:button onclick="submit" text="Submit" runat="server">
<p><asp:label id="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:label></p>



</asp:button></asp:textbox></form></body></html>
```

Comment: Please show us the rendered HTML on the page.

Comment: Just updated it including the rendered HTML. Thanks.

Comment: You're clearly not running this on a server if that is your rendered HTML.

Comment: My mistake. I actually opened the .asp file with chrome when this renders. I just ran it through the server and I get this message: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: You need to go into IIS and add .asp extension

Comment: The `.asp` extension is for "Classic ASP", not ASP.NET which is what you're using.

Comment: Is there a way to use only Classic ASP not .NET? Every tutorial I've found talks about .NET.

Comment: I found one, nevermind. I feel pretty stupid. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need language; it is VB in your case. I assume you are using Visual Studio.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <script runat="server">
        Public Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            lbl1.Text = "Your name is " + txt1.Text
        End Sub
    </script>

    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        Enter your name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" />
        </p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```